# ProgrammingError at /blog/ relation "blog_post" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "blog_post" WHERE "blog_po

Tags: django, heroku

I had finished deploying my django app on heroku. But, when I went there to see it, I saw this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /blog/
relation "blog_post" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "blog_post" WHERE "blog_po...
```

If you want to see the full error message, go here: https://fathomless-lowlands-24834.herokuapp.com/blog/

I could not include the entire message as it was really long, and exceeded the limit of words I was allowed to have in my question.
I can't even understand where the error is. I tried searching for this online, but did not find any response that helped me.

Here is my `post_list` view function:

```
def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,
                 'blog/post/list.html',
                 {'page': page,
                  'posts': posts,
                  'tag': tag})
```

Comment: can you show us your code ?

Comment: which file should I show?

Comment: `/app/blog/views.py : post_list`

Comment: wait a min let me do it

Comment: The table `blog_post` does not exist. Show us your database.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand. what exactly should I show?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no error in the code.

Run `heroku run python manage.py migrate`. After the migration works properly, reload the page and you should not see any errors.

Comment: I run this command 'heroku run python manage.py migrate' to migrate heroku but I still get that error .Do you have any suggestion.